# How to Intercept last Opened/expanded node of a Flex Tree

Tags: apache-flex, treeview, adobe, components

I have a partially populated Tree component and I have to invoke a remote service when User expand (not when he select) a node to retrieve it's leafs. 
How I know witch node have bee selected.

I'm using Flex 3.3.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this way:

//The Gui

```
<mx:Tree id="tree" itemOpening="retriveLeafs(event)"/>
```

// The logic

```
   public function retriveLeafs(event:TreeEvent):void {
       var vo:MyCustomVO = event.item as MyCustomVO;
       //...
   }
```